# Localhost refused to connect - Bitnami does not display any server

Tags: sql, wordpress, apache, wamp, bitnami

I have created a Wordpress website locally using the Bitnami installer. Everything was going well and I have managed to finish designing the website until something happened.

I'm not sure if it is in any way related to the issue but my computer automatically installed a Windows update, since then I cannot access the website that I created locally. It says that,

This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Again, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the update, because I have already uninstalled the updated and it's still the same. What's also weird is that my Bitnami managers servers aren't running any servers, and actually there are no servers under it at all.

I am confused and lost as to how this happened and what's the solution for this. I would appreciate any help or pointed anyone can give me. Please see attached Photos.

[This is the initial message when I try to access the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG7fj.png)

[Clicking on the go to application and open my phpadmin doesn't do or open anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4RMm.png)

[There are no servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk3Tw.png)
[There are no events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnXoF.png)

Comment: Check your ports? Try uninstalling, restart your machine and then install it. For Wordpress, try using virtual host.

Comment: Check you firewall and what it is allowing or Not on ports 80 and 3306

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If the Bitnami manager doesn't show the services is because they are not installed in the server or they got renamed during the upgrade process. Let's try to reinstall the services again.

- First of all, you will need open your installation directory and double-click on the use_wordpress.bat file. That will open the command prompt in Windows
- Run the remove command

```
serviceinstall.bat REMOVE
```

- If the console is closed, open it again and run the install command

```
serviceinstall.bat INSTALL
```

- Check if the services are now up and running in the Bitnami Manager tool

Comment: Hello Jota, thank you so much for your response. I know this might be a dumb question but how do I even run these commands you have given me? I am very new to this and so I don't want to make any additional mistakes that might lead to another problem.

Comment: Hi Elle, if you follow the instructions, you will open the Windows command prompt in the first step. Once it's open, you need to run the commands I mentioned in that command prompt

Comment: Hi Jota, thank you so much. I've already done this actually, but there doesn't seem to be any effects on my server manager.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to look at my concern from your end? I've ran the support tool last time.

Comment: To take a look at the bnsupport information, you will need to open a thread in the Bitnami Community forum (https://community.bitnami.com).

Comment: Hi jota. I have actually opened a thread on the bitnami community as well, you can refer to this link for my post. https://community.bitnami.com/t/localhost-refused-to-connect-bitnami-server-manager-is-not-running-any-servers-at-all/94523/9

Comment: I have tried the steps laid out by the other contributors but nothings seems to be working for my case.